# Regarding critics towards the New Deal

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, history, economy

I am a Danish student writing a paper on the Great Depression, and the political initiatives after the crash focusing on the New Deal. But I've had a problem finding sources of prominent people (With quotes) who were critics of the New Deal and its laws. For example some quotes from a Supreme Court Justice who overturned his laws.

Comment: If you look under the [Judiciary Reorganization Bill of 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_Reorganization_Bill_of_1937) on Wikipedia, you'll find a list of Supreme Court cases.  You should be able to find the text of the decisions, concurrences, and dissents that will have useful quotes.  Also, this might fit better on History.SE, as you don't seem to want information on *current* politics nor political science.  It's also not uncommon to ask people with homework to show what they've done already.  You may want to add that to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a good [list of people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_critics_of_the_New_Deal) who were critics of the new deal. You're not likely to find any judiciary commentary on it because (in theory) the Judicial branch is supposed to be politically neutral and not express personal opinions on policy. Any concurrences or dissents you read will (again, in theory) be based on application of existing law, no matter how much the justices agree with a point.